# связать <textarea> с кнопкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть

```
<textarea id='message' placeholder='hello!'></texarea>
```

и кнопка

```
<div id='button'>Send</div>
```

Какой код нужен для того, чтобы при вводе в  текста кнопка меняла свой цвет?

Comment: Собственно, кнопки не вижу. Вижу только блок с `id='button'`

Comment: Через data-атрибуты можно.

Comment: условная 'кнопка', кнопка-div. легче самому создать новую, чем кастомизировать исходную

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD:**
Под нажимом профессиональной общественности обновляю ответ (теперь цвет меняется не от любого нажатия кнопок, а только если в поле вводится текст + если текст удалить бэкспейсом, цвет возвращается в исходное состояние):

```js
$('#message').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() != 0) {
     $('#button').css('background-color', 'red');
  }
  else {
     $('#button').css('background', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
#button {
  width: 32px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='message' placeholder='hello!'></textarea> <br />и кнопка <div id='button'>Send</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

**первый вариант**
В самом общем виде можно сделать так:

```js
$('#message').keydown(function(){
   $('#button').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
#button {
  width: 32px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='message' placeholder='hello!'></textarea> <br />и кнопка <div id='button'>Send</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Это если без уточнения, как именно должна менять, на какой цвет и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, совершенно не подумал о событии keydown. Всё на поверхности, как и обычно

Comment: @ЛёшаПоворознюк, если ответ помог, примите его, поставив галочку

Comment: поставил, буду знать впредь

Comment: Цвет меняется, даже если я просто нажму Ctrl с фокусом в textarea, а это никакой не ввод текста

Comment: @andreymal а Вы не жмите ctrl :) На самом деле понятно, что можно проверять textarea на ненулевой val() по keyup, да и отменять изменение цвета, если текст удалён бэкспейсом, тоже можно - но таких уточнений в задании не было

Comment: В задании было — изменять цвет при вводе текста. Вы, наверно, можете интерпретировать это как «изменять цвет *не только* при вводе текста», но я бреюсь бритвой Оккама и не хочу так интерпретировать :)

Comment: @andreymal, Вы меня устыдили, и я исправился :)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно так, тут Ваша разметка и Ваши id, class'ы

```js
$('#textarea').bind('input propertychange', function() {

      $("#btn").addClass('active');

});
```

```css
#btn.active {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: тоже симпатичный вариант, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('input', () => {
  if (document.querySelector('textarea').value !== '') {
    document.querySelector('#button').style.background = 'red';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#button').style.background = 'white';
  }
})
```

```css
#button {
  width: 32px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='message' placeholder='hello!'></textarea>
<div id='button'>Send</div>
```

Comment: а к вам сообщения из комнаты about SVG не приходят?

Comment: @Alexandr_T нет...

Comment: странно, загляни, пожалуйста туда https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Comment: @Alexandr_T, посмотри вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769740/Как-данный-пример-на-на-css-сделать-на-чистом-svg

Comment: спасибо, уже читаю