# Как данный пример анимации CSS сделать на чистом SVG SMIL

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация

Как данный пример полностью реализовать на `svg`, без единой строчки `css`. `css` можно стилизовать только сам тег `svg`

```css
*,
* ::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#iconWrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.iconLine {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform .5s, background .1s .3s, top .5s .5s;
}

.lineOne {
  top: 5px;
}

.lineTwo {
  top: 20px;
}

.lineThree {
  top: 35px;
}

#iconWrapper:hover .lineOne {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  transition: transform .5s .5s, top .5s;
}

#iconWrapper:hover .lineTwo {
  top: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: transform .5s .5s, background .5s .3s, top .5s;
}

#iconWrapper:hover .lineThree {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transition: transform .5s .5s, top .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="iconWrapper">
    <div class="iconLine lineOne"></div>
    <div class="iconLine lineTwo"></div>
    <div class="iconLine lineThree"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы было легче сравнивать команды анимации `CSS` и `SVG`,- наименования классов, уникальных идентификаторов будут одинаковы в обоих примерах.
*Анимацию `SVG` можно сделать по разному, очень коротким кодом, но опять же, для лучшего понимания будем делать подробно, последовательно и нудно.*

- Линии нарисованы с помощью `<polyline>` ширина линий задана -
  `stroke-width="4"`

```html
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   width="50" height="50"  viewBox="0 0 50 50"  >
<g   stroke-width="4" stroke="white" >
 
 <rect id="iconWrapper" width="50" height="50"  fill="#000" /> 
  
  <polyline id="lineOne" points="5 10 45 10"  />
  <polyline id="lineTwo" points="5 25 45 25"   /> 
  <polyline id="lineThree" points="5 40 45 40"  />
</g> 
</svg>
```

*Для повторения примера анимации на CSS,
необходимо сделать несколько последовательных анимаций SVG:*

1. Верхняя и нижняя линии сдвигаются навстречу друг другу в одну позицию со средней линией.
2. Средняя линия исчезает, так как её не должно быть видно при повороте крайних линий
3. Поворот одной линии против часовой стрелки на -45°
4. Поворот второй линии по часовой стрелке на 45°
5. Обратный поворот наклонных линий в горизонтальное положение.
6. Появление средней линии
7. Возврат первой и третьей линии на исходную позицию

**#1.**  Анимация начинается после клика по чёрному квадрату. `begin="iconWrapper.click"`

```html
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   width="50" height="50"  viewBox="0 0 50 50"  >

 <rect id="iconWrapper" width="50" height="50"  fill="#000" />   
   <g   stroke-width="4" stroke="white" pointer-events="none"; >
   <polyline id="lineOne" points="5 10 45 10"  />
  <polyline id="lineTwo" points="5 25 45 25"   /> 
  <polyline id="lineThree" points="5 40 45 40"  />
</g> 

<!-- Анимация движения верхней линии к центральной линии  --> 
<animate id="an1_Line1" xlink:href="#lineOne" attributeName="points" begin="iconWrapper.click" dur="0.25s"
values="5 10 45 10;5 25 45 25" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />
<!--  нижней линии к центральной линии  -->
<animate id="an1_Line3" xlink:href="#lineThree" attributeName="points" begin="iconWrapper.click" dur="0.25s"
values="5 40 45 40;5 25 45 25" fill="freeze" restart="never" />

</svg>
```

К первой анимации придётся давать много пояснений, дальше пойдёт легче

`pointer-events="none"`
Так как белые линии находятся выше чёрного квадрата, необходимо сделать их прозрачными для клика, если курсор попадает на них.
Другими словами,- клик, как команда для начала анимации сработает при любом расположении курсора, хоть на белых линиях, хоть на чёрном фоне.

`attributeName="points"` - атрибут, который будет анимироваться,- внутри него набор координат начальной и конечной точек одной линии - `<polyline>`.

`values="5 10 45 10;5 25 45 25"` - до точки запятой координаты линии в начальном положении, после точки с запятой координаты в конечном положении.

`fill="freeze"` - заморозка линии в конечном положении.
 `restart="never"` - защита от повторного мгновенного клика, иначе начнется повторная анимация не дожидаясь окончания исходной анимации.

**#2.** Средняя линия исчезает, так как её не должно быть видно при повороте крайних линий

```html
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   width="50" height="50"  viewBox="0 0 50 50"  >

 <rect id="iconWrapper" width="50" height="50"  fill="#000" />   
   <g   stroke-width="4" stroke="white" pointer-events="none"; >
   <polyline id="lineOne" points="5 10 45 10"  />
  <polyline id="lineTwo" points="5 25 45 25"   /> 
  <polyline id="lineThree" points="5 40 45 40"  />
</g> 

<!-- Анимация движения верхней к центральной линии  --> 
<animate id="an1_Line1" xlink:href="#lineOne" attributeName="points" begin="iconWrapper.click" dur="0.25s"
values="5 10 45 10;5 25 45 25" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />
<!--  нижней линии к центральной линии  -->
<animate id="an1_Line3" xlink:href="#lineThree" attributeName="points" begin="iconWrapper.click" dur="0.25s"
values="5 40 45 40;5 25 45 25" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
 <!-- Анимация исчезновения средней линии  --> 
<animate id="hide" xlink:href="#lineTwo" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" dur="1ms" begin="an1_Line3.end" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" /> 

</svg>
```

Анимации исчезновения средней линии не видно, так как средняя линия находится под другими линиями, но её следует убрать заранее до вращения других линий.

`attributeName="opacity" values="1;0"` - прозрачность линии изменяется от нуля до 100%
`begin="an1_Line3.end"` - начало анимации сразу после завершения предыдущей анимации, сближения линий.

**#3.** Поворот одной линии против часовой стрелки на -45°
**#4.** Поворот второй линии по часовой стрелке на 45°

```html
<doctype! html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   width="50" height="50"  viewBox="0 0 50 50"  >

 <rect id="iconWrapper" width="50" height="50"  fill="#000" />   
   <g   stroke-width="4" stroke="white" pointer-events="none"; >
   <polyline id="lineOne" points="5 10 45 10"  />
  <polyline id="lineTwo" points="5 25 45 25"   /> 
  <polyline id="lineThree" points="5 40 45 40"  />
</g> 

<!-- Анимация движения верхней линии к центральной линии  --> 
<animate id="an1_Line1" xlink:href="#lineOne" attributeName="points" begin="iconWrapper.click" dur="0.25s"
values="5 10 45 10;5 25 45 25" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />
<!-- и нижней линии к центральной линии  -->
<animate id="an1_Line3" xlink:href="#lineThree" attributeName="points" begin="iconWrapper.click" dur="0.25s"
values="5 40 45 40;5 25 45 25" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
 <!-- Анимация исчезновения средней линии  --> 
<animate id="hide" xlink:href="#lineTwo" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" dur="1ms" begin="an1_Line1.end" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotactive" />   

<!-- Анимация поворота верхней и нижней на 45 градусов --> 
<animateTransform id="R_line1" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#lineOne"
      type="rotate"  values="0 25 25; -45 25 25" begin="hide.end" dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />  
 <animateTransform id="" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#lineThree"
      type="rotate"  values="0 25 25; 45 25 25" begin="hide.end" dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />   
 
</svg>
```

`type="rotate"  values="0 25 25; 45 25 25"` - поворот по часовой стрелке на 45° 
 группа цифр после точки с запятой - `;` конечное положение линии`45 25 25` - угол и координаты центра вращения.
 `begin="hide.end"` - анимация вращения начнется по окончанию анимации сокрытия линии

**#5.** Обратный поворот наклонных линий в горизонтальное положение.
**#6.** Появление средней линии
**#7.** Возврат первой и третьей линии на исходную позицию

```html
<doctype! html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   width="50" height="50"  viewBox="0 0 50 50"  >

 <rect id="iconWrapper" width="50" height="50"  fill="#000" />   
   <g   stroke-width="4" stroke="white" pointer-events="none"; >
   <polyline id="lineOne" points="5 10 45 10"  />
  <polyline id="lineTwo" points="5 25 45 25"   /> 
  <polyline id="lineThree" points="5 40 45 40"  />
</g> 

<!-- Анимация движения верхней линии к центральной линии  --> 
<animate id="an1_Line1" xlink:href="#lineOne" attributeName="points" begin="iconWrapper.click" dur="0.25s"
values="5 10 45 10;5 25 45 25" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />
<!-- и нижней линии к центральной линии  -->
<animate id="an1_Line3" xlink:href="#lineThree" attributeName="points" begin="iconWrapper.click" dur="0.25s"
values="5 40 45 40;5 25 45 25" fill="freeze" restart="never" />
 <!-- Анимация исчезновения средней линии  --> 
<animate id="hide" xlink:href="#lineTwo" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" dur="1ms" begin="an1_Line1.end" fill="freeze"  />   

<!-- Анимация поворота верхней и нижней на 45 градусов --> 
<animateTransform id="R_line1" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#lineOne"
      type="rotate" begin="hide.end" values="0 25 25; -45 25 25" dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />  
 <animateTransform id="R_line3" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#lineThree"
      type="rotate" begin="hide.end" values="0 25 25; 45 25 25" dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />    

 <!-- Анимация обратного поворота верхней и нижней на 45 градусов -->   
<animateTransform id="L_line1" xlink:href="#lineOne" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" 
      type="rotate" begin="R_line3.end+1s" values="-45 25 25;0 25 25 " dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />  
 <animateTransform id="L_line3" xlink:href="#lineThree" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" 
      type="rotate" begin="R_line3.end+1s" values="45 25 25;0 25 25 " dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />  
   
    <!-- Анимация появления средней линии -->
   <animate id="visibleLine" xlink:href="#lineTwo" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" dur="1ms" begin="L_line3.end" fill="freeze" restart="never" /> 
  
  <!-- Анимация движения  линий от центральной линии --> 
 <animate id="an2_Line1" xlink:href="#lineOne" attributeName="points" begin="L_line3.end+0.1s" dur="0.25s"
values="5 25 45 25;5 10 45 10" fill="freeze" restart="never"  />
<animate id="an2_Line3" xlink:href="#lineThree" attributeName="points" begin="L_line3.end+0.1s" dur="0.25s"
values="5 25 45 25;5 40 45 40" fill="freeze" restart="never" />    
 
</svg>
```

`SVG SMIL` анимация,- это декларативная анимация. Поэтому у неё нет переменных.
 То есть негде хранить и считать клики в интерактивном режиме анимации.
 Поэтому для выполнения таких действий, как в примере автора вопроса, необходимо всё таки подключать или `CSS` в виде скрытых чекбоксов или `JS`.

SVG хорошо работает в паре c  `CSS`, `JS`. Стили `CSS` можно добавлять внутри файла `SVG` в  стилях представления:

вот так:

```
<rect class="rect1" width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke="black" />
```

или так:

```
<rect class="rect1" width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:red; stroke:black"/>
```

или добавлять стили внутри файла svg:

```
<svg>
<style>
 .rect {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 fill:red;
 stroke:black;
  }
</style> 
<rect class="rect1" x="10" y="20"/>
</svg>
```

Вот перевод отличной статьи , в которой автор - **Sara Soueidan**, попыталась кратко и доходчиво на примерах изложить основы анимации:

[Руководство по анимации SVG (SMIL)](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/rukovodstvo-po-animacii-svg-smil.html)

Comment: Ты просто красавец....

Comment: @Air спасибо, если у людей хватит сил изучить много буков, то надеюсь, будет очень полезно для освоения нового уровня знаний. Я имею ввиду статью по ссылке :) Если будут вопросы, задавай, не стесняйся здесь или в чате об SVG https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Comment: Alexandr_TT, помоги человеку, а то я ему не смогу грамотно  пример показать    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777436/Как-грамотно-сверстать-подобные-блоки?noredirect=1#comment1217497_777436

Comment: @Air если успею :) А то вон сколько людей там откликнулись/ Посмотри в разделе SVG я новый пост, почти спецом для тебя перевел по связке анимаций css - svg https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/777708/28748

Comment: Кстати, седня заметил, что в этом ответе второй раз клик не работает

Comment: @Air так комментарии мои почитай. Это работает защита restart="never" защита от повторного запуска. Иначе всё ломается. Невозможно реализовать логику при pure SVG, негде хранить клики

Comment: Ну подумаю как решить с помощью JS