# Как грамотно сверстать подобные блоки?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как грамотнее сверстать то, что на скрине ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробности: 2 блока, у каждого блока свой bg, блоки разделены наклонными линиями (рыжая и бледно-рыжая). При сужение окна, пересечение линий должно оставаться в центре.

Что делать, сразу готовить bg изображения с резанным 'низом', или 'резать' низ через css, но тогда как зафиксировать полоски по низу этого 'резанного' bg?

Comment: может просто фоном, а у фона есть настройка для центрирования

Comment: лучши вариант `svg`

Comment: можно легко `css  clip-path` но учти  в `EDGE & IE`  не будет рабатать

Comment: >лучши вариант svg - а можно наглядный пример?

Comment: >можно легко css clip-path но учти в EDGE & IE не будет рабатать - а вот это не совсем годится...

Comment: @MikeRo я щас с тел, завтра пожалуйста

Comment: Полная ширина, skew, transform: translateX(-+50%), rotate(-+30grad). Должно получиться.

Comment: @Air добрый день! Как будет возможность, напишите пожалуйста наглядный пример с svg, спасибо!

Comment: @MikeRo, поверь на слово, мой пример был бы хуже))))  Гуру `svg` у нас тут Alexandr_TT....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Пример SVG

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >

<rect id="rect6" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<path id="rightLine" d="M1197 261 600.25624 376.79371c0 0 0 21.41258-0.25624 23.20629l597-113z"  style="fill:#ffa896;stroke-width:4;stroke:#ffa896"/>
<path id="leftLine" d="M0 261 661.53747 388.79371 598.97502 400.51249 0 287Z"  style="fill:#ca432b;stroke-width:4;stroke:#ca432b"/></svg>
```

*Изображение адаптивно, соединение линий всегда находится в центре, пропорции сохраняются.*

Добавлять svg можно инлайн или через `background`

**Пример добавления инлайн SVG**

Стили представления SVG (`fill`, `stroke`и другие) переносим в CSS/
Стили старайтесь определять один раз, не дублируйте. У svg сложная система иерархии. 
Обертываем svg - `<div class="container">код svg</div>`

Если необходима адаптивность задавайте размеры контейнеру в процентах.

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#rectFon{
    fill:black;
}
#rightLine {
    fill:#ffa896;
    stroke-width:4;
    stroke:#ffa896";
}
#leftLine {
    fill:#ca432b;
    stroke-width:4;
    stroke:#ca432b;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1200 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
        <rect id="rectFon" width="100%" height="100%"  />
        <path id="rightLine" d="M1197 261 600.25624 376.79371c0 0 0 21.41258-0.25624 23.20629l597-113z"  />
        <path id="leftLine" d="M0 261 661.53747 388.79371 598.97502 400.51249 0 287Z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Конечно! Благодарю, очень помогли!