# Преобразование анимации SVG SMIL в анимацию CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Мой текущий пример SVG анимирован с использованием анимации SVG SMIL:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg height="512px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="512px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="scale(0.8) translate(-0.6, -0.6)">
        <g id="spinner">
            <path d="M50 15A35 35 0 1 0 74.787 25.213" fill="none" stroke="#19a29c" stroke-width="8px"/>
            <path d="M50 0L50 30L66 15L50 0" fill="#19a29c"/>
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1.5s" from="0 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" to="360 50 50" type="rotate"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

`SVG SMIL` анимация не поддерживается  `IE`, см. - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil)

Я бы хотел заменить анимационную часть `SVG` анимацией `CSS`, сделав анимацию более широко поддерживаемой браузерами,-  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Примечание переводчика:
 *c какими ограничениями `IE` поддерживает анимацию, можно посмотреть по той же ссылке, что дал автор вопроса. См. во вкладке `Known issues`. Получается, что практически мало, что поддерживает `IE`.*

**Как я могу заменить следующую анимацию SVG SMIL анимацией CSS?**

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1.5s" from="0 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" to="360 50 50" type="rotate"/>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37351488/7394871)

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37351488/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Анимация, выполняемая с помощью `SMIL`, представляет собой анимацию вращения, в которой элемент `#spinner` поворачивается на `360` градусов каждые `1,5` секунды и имеет бесконечный цикл.

Последние два параметра  `animateTransform attributeName` svg являются `transform-origin` `css`, поэтому для создания эквивалента CSS необходимо выполнить следующее:

- Создайте `animation @keyframe`- правило, которое осуществляет вращение
  `rotate() from 0 deg to 360 deg`.
- Примените анимацию к элементу `#spinner`, используя свойство
  анимации. Установите его продолжительность как `1,5s`, итерацию
  сделайте бесконечной и `timing function` линейной.
  Они могут быть выполнены с использованием  сокращенной записи анимации или  подробно с использованием  индивидуальных имен свойств анимации: `animation-name`, `animation-duration`, `animation-iteration-count` и `animation-timing-function`
- Установите `transform-origin` - `50px 50px` для `#spinner`

```css
#spinner {
  animation: rotate 1.5s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg height="512px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="512px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="scale(0.8) translate(-0.6, -0.6)">
    <g id="spinner">
      <path d="M50 15A35 35 0 1 0 74.787 25.213" fill="none" stroke="#19a29c" stroke-width="8px" />
      <path d="M50 0L50 30L66 15L50 0" fill="#19a29c" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37351665/7394871)

Похожий топик:

[Как данный пример анимации CSS сделать на чистом SVG SMIL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/769740/28748)